# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module webpack-typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Here is webpack.config.ts

```js
// const path = require("path");
import path from "path";
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from "html-webpack-plugin";
import CopyWebpackPlugin from "copy-webpack-plugin";
import webpack from "webpack";

import WebpackDevServer from "webpack-dev-server";

declare module "webpack" {
    interface Configuration {
        devServer?: WebpackDevServer.Configuration;
    }
}
const config: webpack.Configuration = {
  mode: "development",
  target: "web",
  entry: ["regenerator-runtime/runtime", "./src/index.tsx"],
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.join(__dirname, "build"),
    publicPath: "/",
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".css"],
    alias: {
      // add as many aliases as you like!
      components: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/components"),
    },
    fallback: {
      // path: require.resolve("path-browserify"),
      fs: false,
      assert: require.resolve("assert/"),
      os: require.resolve("os-browserify/browser"),
      constants: require.resolve("constants-browserify"),
    },
  },
  devtool: "eval-cheap-source-map",
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.(ts|tsx)/, loader: "babel-loader", exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.css$/, use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"] },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              name: "[name].[contenthash].[ext]",
              outputPath: "fonts/",
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "svg-url-loader",
            options: {
              limit: 10000,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "build"),
    historyApiFallback: true,
    overlay: true,
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: "esBUild",
      template: "src/index.html",
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [{ from: "assets", to: "assets" }],
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      process: "process/browser",
      Buffer: ["buffer", "Buffer"],
      React: "react",
    }),
  ],
};

export default config;
```

here is tsconfig.json:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // The standard typing to be included in the type checking process.
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    // Whether to allow JavaScript files to be compiled.
    "allowJs": true,
    //This allows default imports from modules with no default export in the type checking process.
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    // Whether to skip type checking of all the type declaration files (*.d.ts).
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    // This enables compatibility with Babel.
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true,
    // Ensures that the casing of referenced file names is consistent during the type checking process.
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    //  This allows modules to be in .json files which are useful for configuration files.
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "components": ["components/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

THis is the error I get :

```
import path from "path";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I googled it and see some people suggest adding `"type":"module"`, it did not work.

in tsconfig.json

```
 "module": "es6" /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */,
```

I tried each option but this did not work neither.

If I discard the typescript configuration, set up webpack with common.js, it works

Also .babelrc

```js
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-react",
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"
  ]
}
```

Comment: When/where are you getting this error? During the build process?

Comment: @FelixKling yeah. when webpack compiles

Comment: It's possible that webpack doesn't load the configuration as a module but differently. But that's just speculation on my side, I don't have any more insights on that.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have to change to `"module": "commonjs",` inside `tsconfig.json`. Refer https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have to install typescript types of plugins (vscode suggested it after restart the ide).

For example:

For dotenv-webpack package, I installed @types/dotenv-webpack.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-languages/#typescript) section of the Webpack configuration documentation:

> The above sample assumes version >= 2.7 or newer of TypeScript is used with the new esModuleInterop and allowSyntheticDefaultImports compiler options in your tsconfig.json file.
> Note that you'll also need to check your tsconfig.json file. If the module in compilerOptions in tsconfig.json is commonjs, the setting is complete, else webpack will fail with an error. This occurs because ts-node does not support any module syntax other than commonjs.
> There are three solutions to this issue:
>
> - Modify tsconfig.json.
> - Modify tsconfig.json and add settings for ts-node.
> - Install tsconfig-paths.

You've set the correct values for "esModuleInterop" and "allowSyntheticDefaultImports" in your tsconfig.json, so, to get rid of the error, you should do one of the above three options.

The first one suggests you to change the "module" compiler option's value to "commonjs".
The second one allows you to keep the "module" option's value as is, but you should add the settings for ts-node in your tsconfig.json.
The third one requires additional package installation and a separate TS configuration file.